# Unable to connect to OpenSSH server from local .NET application

Tags: c#, ssh, openssh, ssh.net

I have a remote server running Windows 2022 with OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH Server installed. I am able to connect to the remote machine with RDP with an Admin account and everything looks like it is correct. Services are installed and running. However, when I try to connect to the same server from my local machine I get a permission denied error.

I am trying to connect using a .NET application using the SSH.Net library but also am trying with command prompt and get the same error either way saying "Permission denied, please try again". I am typing in the host, username and password the same as I do in RDP.

Here is my .NET code which I wrote based on this article:
https://codeburst.io/working-with-sftp-in-net-core-f1f464ab06f8
This fails at the client.Connect with the error of:

[image]

```
var client = new SftpClient(sftpConfiguration.Host, sftpConfiguration.Port, sftpConfiguration.Username, sftpConfiguration.Password);
            using (client)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    var files = client.ListDirectory(sftpConfiguration.RemotePath);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {

                    }
                    return files;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    client.Disconnect();
                    logger.LogError(exception, $"Failed in listing files under [{sftpConfiguration.RemotePath}]");
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Disconnect();
                }
            }
```

Here is my command prompt:

[image]

Are there configurations that I am missing for the OpenSSH Server?

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant or not but my password does contain several special characters including: )(!;@?=$ . Would that possibly be causing the issue?

Answer (score -1):

This issue was in fact due to special characters in the password. Once I removed those I was able to connect without issues.